# ajax request jsonp file accessible in console, but nothing shows up when console.log(data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Trying to make an ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mysitedotcom/blog/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback"
});
function jsonpCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

I can see the output via Sources in my browser inspector tool, but nothing is outputting in the `console.log(data);`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the URL really supports JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mysitedotcom/blog/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: jsonpCallback
});
function jsonpCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

There's simple case of use [JSONP in JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).